# Every non-zero-divisor in a Noetherian local ring is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

In Chapter 11 of Atiyah-Macdonald, the authors prove that for a ring $A$, maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal $\mathfrak{q}$, we have that if $M$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module, $x \in A$ is not a zero-divisor in $M$, and $M' = M / x M$, then $\deg \chi_\mathfrak{q}^{M'} \leq \deg \chi_\mathfrak{q}^M - 1$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\mathfrak{q}$ (Proposition 11.8).

The authors then state the following corollary and proof:

> *Corollary 11.9*: If $A$ is a Noetherian local ring, $x$ a non-zero-divisor in $A$, then $d(A / (x)) \leq d(A) - 1$
>
> *Proof*: Put $M = A$ in (11.8).

It is clear to me that taking $M = A$, we have a finitely-generated $A$-module since $A$ is Noetherian, but in order to apply the result, we need to know that $(x)$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-primary. **How do we know that any non-zero-divisor in a local Noetherian ring generates an $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal?**

It seems to me that if $A$ has dimension greater than one then this should not be the case. For example, if we localize the coordinate ring of an irreducible (smooth) variety in $\mathbb{A}^3$ at a point on that variety that lies on some irreducible subvariety, shouldn't that give a local ring, where the ideal corresponding to the subvariety is a prime strictly contained in the maximal ideal? Then the ideal generated by any point inside that prime will have radical equal to the prime instead of equal to the maximal ideal, so will not be $\mathfrak{m}$-primary? For concreteness: Wouldn't any non-zero-divisor in the image of $\langle y - x^2, z \rangle$ in $(k[x,y,z]/\langle x^2 + y^2 - z \rangle)_{(x,y,z)}$ generate an ideal that is not $(x,y,z)$-primary?

Comment: Your bolded claim is false: take $x\in k[x,y,z]_{(x,y,z)}$. But that's fine, since you don't need that claim to prove the corollary - you want $M=A$ and to take $\mathfrak{q}$ to be the maximal ideal of $A$. (Why would you want to take $\mathfrak{q}=(x)$?)

Comment: oh I see, thanks for the quick reply! I don't know how I got in my head that we wanted $\mathfrak{q} = (x)$, but somehow once it was there it stuck. This is my first read through, so I'm still getting my bearings with all the definitions. Thanks again for pointing that out!